# Can't convert firetstore timestamp to Flutter DateTime

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I can't convert firestore timestamp to flutter date, and really tried near everything( including using Timestamp instead of DateTime in model), any idea how to fix this bug. Here's my code below

**Model From Map**

```
  factory Event.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Event(
      id: map['id'],
      organizerId: map['organizerId'],
      organizerName: map['organizerName'],
      eventTime: map['eventTime'].toDate(),
      maxApplicationCount: map['maxApplicationCount'],
      attendedUsers: List<String>.from(map['attendedUsers']),
      eventText: map['eventText'],
      location: Location.fromMap(map['location']),
    );
  }
```

**Error**

```
 NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method 'toDate'.
```

**Using Timestamp Instead of DateTime**

```
  factory Event.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Event(
      id: map['id'],
      organizerId: map['organizerId'],
      organizerName: map['organizerName'],
      eventTime: map['eventTime'],
      maxApplicationCount: map['maxApplicationCount'],
      attendedUsers: List<String>.from(map['attendedUsers']),
      eventText: map['eventText'],
      location: Location.fromMap(map['location']),
    );
  }
```

**Error**

```
flutter: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp'
```

Any idea how to convert Firestore timestamp to dateTime?

**map['eventTime']**

```
Timestamp(seconds=1620583200, nanoseconds=0)
```

Comment: Can you just show map['eventTime'] so we can actually see what we're working with here?

Comment: sure, edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just make eventTime as dynamic and try eventModel.eventTime.toDate() wherever you use it

This works for me.
Set and get timestamp like this

```
class EventModel{
      dynamic timestamp;
      SiteModel({this.deletedTimestamp});
      EventModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        timestamp=json['timestamp'];
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data =<String, dynamic>{};
        data["timestamp"]=FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
        return data;
      }
```

Use it like this

```
eventModel.timestamp.toDate().toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this package it's a real booster

package link on pub.dev : [link](https://pub.dev/packages/mapdescriptor)

Usage
To use the MapDescriptor package, simply import it and create a new instance of the MapDescriptor class:

```
import 'package:map_descriptor/map_descriptor.dart';

MapDescriptor mapDescriptor = MapDescriptor();
```

**Converting TimeStamp va

```
lues to ISO 8601 strings**

To convert TimeStamp values in a map to ISO 8601 strings, use the convertTimeStampToStr method:

Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {
  'date1': TimeStamp(2124545,6565457),
  'date2': {'date3': TimeStamp(1212154,121215545)}
};

Map<String, dynamic> result = mapDescriptor.convertTimeStampToStr(myMap);

print(result);
// output: {date1: 2023-04-24T16:47:36.975, date2: {date3: 2023-04-24T16:47:36.975}}
```

**Converting ISO 8601 strings to TimeStamp values**

To convert ISO 8601 string values in a map to TimeStamp objects, use the convertStrToTimeStamp method:

```
Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {
  'date1': '2023-04-24T16:47:36.975',
  'date2': {'date3': '2023-04-24T16:47:36.975'}
};

Map<String, dynamic> result = mapDescriptor.convertStrToTimeStamp(myMap);

print(result);
// output: {date1: Timestamp(seconds=1685065656, nanoseconds=975000000), date2: {date3: Timestamp(seconds=1685065656, nanoseconds=975000000)}}
```

**Checking for TimeStamp or ISO 8601 string values**

To determine if a map contains any TimeStamp or ISO 8601 string values, use the containsTimeStamp and containsISO8601Str methods, respectively:

```
Map<String, dynamic> myMap1 = {'date1': TimeStamp(4545412,2121454)};
Map<String, dynamic> myMap2 = {'date1': {'date3': TimeStamp(412115,121244)}, 'date2': {'date3': '2023-04-24T16:47:36.975'}};

bool containsDateTime1 = mapDescriptor.containsTimeStamp(myMap1); // true
bool containsDateTime2 = mapDescriptor.containsTimeStamp(myMap2); // false

bool containsISO8601Str1 = mapDescriptor.containsISO8601Str(myMap1); // false
bool containsISO8601Str2 = mapDescriptor.containsISO8601Str(myMap2); // true
Storing the map to the persistent storage
 Future setMap(
    String key,
    Map<String, dynamic> myMap,
  ) async {
    await initializePrefs();
    //delete the previous data to prevent error
    await prefs!.setString(key, jsonEncode({}));
    if (MapDescriptor().containsTimeStamp(myMap)) {
      myMap = MapDescriptor().convertTimeStampToStr(myMap);
    }
    //now we can use jsonEncode for myMap 
    // if we kept myMap without converting TimeStamp values
    // the code will throw an error that the method .toJson() is not allowed
    // for TimeStamp values
    return await prefs!.setString(key, jsonEncode(myMap));
  }
```

If the myMap parameter contains a timestamp (as determined by the containsTimeStamp method of the MapDescriptor class), the convertTimeStampToStr method of the MapDescriptor class is called to convert the timestamp to a string.

Finally, the myMap parameter is JSON-encoded and saved to the persistent storage using the setString method of the prefs instance with the specified key.

Overall, this function saves a map of key-value pairs to a persistent storage using SharedPreferences. If the map contains a timestamp, it is converted to a string before being saved. The previous data associated with the specified key is deleted before saving the new data to prevent errors.